# Display Matplotlib spines in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I know how to display spines in Matplotlib. I know how to display a Matplotlib subplot in Tkinter too. But I would like to know how to put the spines in this subplot in Tkinter.

Here is the code to display a subplot in Tkinter :

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

def destroy(e): sys.exit()

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")

f = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)

a.plot(t,s)
a.set_title('Tk embedding')
a.set_xlabel('X axis label')
a.set_ylabel('Y label')

# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

#toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, root )
#toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

button = Tk.Button(master=root, text='Quit', command=sys.exit)
button.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM)

Tk.mainloop()`
```

Here is the code to display spines in Matplotlib :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

image = np.random.uniform(size=(10, 10))
ax.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
ax.set_title('dropped spines')

# Move left and bottom spines outward by 10 points
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('outward', 10))
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 10))
# Hide the right and top spines
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
# Only show ticks on the left and bottom spines
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you use `ax.set_title('...')` in your second code block, you use `a.set_title('...')` in your first block. This pretty much gives away that the methods you can call on `ax`, you can also call on `a`.

Simply use the same code as in the second block, but replace `ax` with `a`, and it should work fine.

---

According to the docs, `ax` and `a` are not exactly the same objects. [`Figure.add_subplot()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) returns an [`Axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) instance, and [`pyplot.subplots()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) returns an [`Axis`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis) object as second output parameter. However, since

> The Axes contains most of the figure elements: Axis...

you can edit the spines in the same way from both.